# How to add <text> and <line> elements to mxGraph graph

Tags: mxgraph

I need to add custom `<line>` and `<text>` elements to SVG that is rendered by the mxGraph library.

Does anyone know how to do it (or is it possible at all)?

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_line.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_text.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround for this by creating a text element (label) with 0-length vertex. 
See http://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/labels.html

```
var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, 'vertexLabelsMovable', 20, 20, 80, 30);
// Places sublabels inside the vertex
var label11 = graph.insertVertex(v1, null, 'Label1', 0.5, 1, 0, 0, null, true);
var label12 = graph.insertVertex(v1, null, 'Label2', 0.5, 0, 0, 0, null, true);
```

But, it's still quite bad solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.addEntry('vertical Line', mxUtils.bind(this, function() {
        var cell = new mxCell('', new mxGeometry(0, 0, 10, 160), 'line;strokeWidth=2;direction=south;html=1;');
        cell.vertex = true;
        this.graph.setAttributeForCell(cell, 'placeholders', '1');
        this.graph.setAttributeForCell(cell, 'capacity', '0');

        return this.createVertexTemplateFromCells([cell], cell.geometry.width, cell.geometry.height, 'Vertical Line');
    }))
```

Vertical line code